# If statement not working with .equals in Java and always showing the answer of else statement

Tags: java, javafx

I am learning Java myself and am trying to make a sign in like app. The if statement doesn't work but the else statement is always working.

Here is the code:

```
package Lessons;

public class Main extends Application {

    Stage window;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Sign in");

        TextField nameInput = new TextField();

        Button button = new Button("Sign In");

        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20,20));
        layout.getChildren().addAll(nameInput, button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 600, 600);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();

        //Checks the username
        String username = "thomas";
        if (nameInput.getText().equals(username)) {
            button.setOnAction(e -> CorrectUsernameReplier.display());}
        else {
            button.setOnAction(e -> WrongUsernameReplier.display());
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't show what I imported because I don't think they are necessary.

This is the code from the **CorrectUsernameReplier**

```
public static void display() {
    Stage window = new Stage();

    //Replies to correct username
    window.setTitle("Correct username");
    window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    StackPane layout = new StackPane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 200, 200);
    Label label = new Label("Signed In");
    layout.getChildren().add(label);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.showAndWait();
```

This is the code from the **WrongUsernameReplier**

```
public static void display() {
    Stage window = new Stage();


    //Replies to incorrect username
    window.setTitle("Incorrect username");
    window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    StackPane layout1 = new StackPane();
    Scene scene1 = new Scene(layout1, 200, 200);
    Label label = new Label("Incorrect Username. Please try again.");
    layout1.getChildren().add(label);
    window.setScene(scene1);
    window.showAndWait();
```

Here are the images if what the error is:

"thomas" is in the TextField and the username string in the code above is also "thomas". But it shows the error you see.

[image: "thomas" is in the TextField and the username string in the code above is also "thomas". But it shows the error you see.]

This is the second image:

This is the screenshot which I type nothing in it. And the respond here is correct.

[image: This is the screenshot which I type nothing in it. And the respond here is correct.]

Can you please help me figure out what is wrong with my code?

Comment: unrelated: java naming conventions please - you are very near to perfect, except that package names should be all lower-case :) And don't use static scope, it's very rarely what you really want.

Comment: @kleopatra I would like to ask you a question. You said don't use static scope so what should I use instead of static scope? I am new to Java so can you help me?

Comment: _I am new to Java_ then I would recommend to start working through a basic tutorial on language basics :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the `if` statement is processed when the view is created `button.setOnAction(e -> WrongUsernameReplier.display());` is executed every time unconditionally. What you are missing is that the check whether or not the username is correct should only be done when the button has been pressed and not on initializing the UI:

```
button.setOnAction(e -> {
    String username = "thomas";

    if (nameInput.getText().equals(username)) {
        CorrectUsernameReplier.display();
    } else {
        WrongUsernameReplier.display();
    }
});
```

or something similar in JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

that because the condition is always false

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ...
    TextField nameInput = new TextField();
    ...
    //Checks the username
    String username = "thomas";
    if (nameInput.getText().equals(username)) {
        button.setOnAction(e -> CorrectUsernameReplier.display());}
    else {
        button.setOnAction(e -> WrongUsernameReplier.display());
    }
}
```

you just created new instance of `TextField` which has empty text, and you compare it with "thomas".

I think you want to do the compression when the button is clicked so  you do this

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    window = primaryStage;
    window.setTitle("Sign in");

    final TextField nameInput = new TextField();

    Button button = new Button("Sign In");

    VBox layout = new VBox(10);
    layout.setPadding(new Insets(20, 20, 20,20));
    layout.getChildren().addAll(nameInput, button);

    Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 600, 600);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();

    button.setOnAction(e -> {
         String username = "thomas";
         if (nameInput.getText().equals(username)) {
               CorrectUsernameReplier.display();
         else {
               WrongUsernameReplier.display();
         }
    });


}
```